# Parse a string value to DateTime object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime

I have a text box that accepts  DataTime string in format: MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.
For example :

Let's say I have selected a datetime : `"12/26/2013 17:37:03"`

I am trying to get the Datetime object using:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out date);
```

But every time it parses the string to:{`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`}

Please anyone correct me here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`hh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) is for `01` to `12`.

Use [`HH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) instead which is for `00` to `23`.

For example;

```
string s = "12/26/2013 17:37:03";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
Console.WriteLine("Is Parsing Successful? {0}", success);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output will be;

```
Is Parsing Successful? True
12/26/2013 5:37:03 PM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/DRgy6F)</kbd>.

But even if you parsing, why still you get a `DateTime` value?

From [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If date, time, and time zone elements are present in s, they must also
>   appear in the order specified by format. If format defines a date with
>   no time element and the parse operation succeeds, **the resulting
>   DateTime value has a time of midnight (00:00:00).**

**NOTE**: Please read [ken2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870604/ken2k)'s comments: [<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839376/parse-a-string-value-to-datetime-object#comment31255877_20839394) and [<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839376/parse-a-string-value-to-datetime-object#comment31256268_20839394). When you define your `date` with a default value like `DateTime date`; You can't know your conversion is successful or not because since these both generate the default value of DateTime (`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`)

- `DateTime date` makes date as `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`
- If your parsing fails, `date` will be also `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

That's why, I change it in my code to `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;` which you can check whether your converssion is successful or not. If it is successful, your `date` will be `12/26/2013 17:37:03`, if it is not, your date will be `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: In addition to your answer, it's worth saying that using the TryParseXXXX implies checking the returned boolean value. 1/1/0001 is the default value for a datetime, but it shouldn't be used to test if the parse method succeeded. TryParseXXX without a `if (... == true/false)` shouldn't exist.

Comment: _But even if you parsing, why still you get a DateTime value?_ -> if the input doesn't match the specified pattern, TryParseXXX doesn't modify the out parameter. In this case, DateTime has a default value because it's a value type.

Comment: @ken2k You are completely right. Thanks. Updated in my answer as in your suggestions.

Comment: Ugh!! @SonerGönül that was really simple, don't know how did I missed that. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the hour issue that other people have already noted. Why use invariant culture? The datetime in your example is US.

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote, trolls are everywhere, but when dealing with cultures I never implicitly convert, especially when receiving values from a web browser.

Comment: if your talking about a web server, that is not the case. different servers (with different culture settings) return different values.

Comment: and it also affects decimal values, too

Answer (score 0):

Your time is in 24 hour format. Therefore, you need to use HH(used for 24 hour format) instead of hh (used for 12 hour format).

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out date);
```

> But every time it parses the string to:{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}

It means that your parsing failed. You need to check the [result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of parsing before proceeding further. You can do it like below.

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
{
     //Parsing successful
}
else
{
     //Parsing failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the Answer:

```
var TimeIn = Application.Current.Properties["date"].ToString();
DateTime InTime = DateTime.ParseExact(TimeIn, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```